# wso2 custom url null pointer

Tags: url, soap, null, wso2

I have followed the procedures here at below url to a T and still have issues:

http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/01/custom-urls-wso2-esb-proxy-services

I can change my url and for soap services it will work without security. If i try and add security it won't work. It also doesn't work for rest services. I am getting a null pointer which the stack trace points the the `POXSecurityHandler` which I gather to be the change from basic auth to soap headers.

Anyone seen this before?

On my second system, soap seems to just ignore authentication after I change the URL.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the custom url. Identified a bug in wso2 4.5.1 which is not present in 4.5.0. Cannot use security with rest services. The poxsecurityhandler which converts basic auth to soap security has a bug.